# Adding multiple admins in config.php

Tags: php, variables, admin, config

I have this code in config.php

```
       //Username of the Administrator
       $admin='1';
```

And my site take user who have "1" ID, but I want to set multiple admins in this variable.
Likewise, I tried some codes like

```
       $admin=arry('1', '2')
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to change the place(s) where you're checking $admin from:

```
if ($userId == $admin) {}
```

to

```
if (in_array($admin, $userId)) {}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to your swift answer, but that's work with add more than one admin in config.php?